# which model should I choose for this question

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, data-analysis, prediction, decision-tree

For example, the problem is: Whether I should buy this laptop or not? (Note that the question is not whether I will buy or not)

I'm new to machine learning and data science, I think I know the basic concept of this question, it's a supervised classification problem, but it's about should or should not, I'm confused if I should use decision tree or other models, many thanks.

Comment: You might be overthinking language semantics in this case. Machine Learning Algorithms don't make a distinction between the "should" or "would". Infact any recommender system (collaborative filtering) will actually recommend things that a user "should" buy. Now whether they would buy it or not depends on how good the system actually is (things like how well the interface is designed, how easy it is to buy, what else have they purchased, discounts etc.) in offering options that the user would be be enticed to buy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can treat it as a classification problem. You can start with collecting the data to train the algorithm and see if you can pick out some more features by looking at the patterns.

Comment: but the problem is whether they SHOULD buy or not instead of they WILL buy or not, is there a difference when we fit in model?

Comment: Ok, I understood what you are trying to ask. So, you actually want it to work like a suggestion giving model i.e whether I should buy it or not. Correct? If I'm correct then what you could do is that you could set the threshold of the model according to your choice. Precisely, you should decide whether you want more precision or more recall for your algorithm. For example, a threshold of 0.7 would mean your accuracy is 70% and recall is 30%. By doing this you would be able to make a suggesting type model according to your choice.